# How to calculate a year and month difference in java

Tags: java

I need to be able to  prompt a user for 2 dates consisting of a month and a year and display the number 
of years and
months between these 2 dates so

this would be the Input: June, 1999

------------------------------ April, 2002

this is the Output:------- 3 years and -2 months

and this is what i need to get, 2 years and 10 months apart.

this is where my code is, any help is appreciated.

```
public class AgeDifference{
public static void main(String[] args){
    //Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String month1 = "June";
    String month2 = "April";
    int year1 = 1999;
    int year2 = 2002;
    int firstMonthNumber = 0;
    int secondMonthNumber = 0;
    int totalYear = 0;
    int totalMonth = 0;
    //input:
    System.out.println("For the first date,");
    System.out.print("Enter month: ");
    //month1 = input.next();
    System.out.print("Enter year: ");
    //year1 = input.nextInt();
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("For the second date,");
    System.out.print("Enter month: ");
    //month2 = input.next();
    System.out.print("Enter year: ");
    //year2 = input.nextInt();
    System.out.println("");

    //processing:
    if (month1.equalsIgnoreCase("January")){      
        firstMonthNumber = 1;
    } else if(month1.equalsIgnoreCase("February")){     
        firstMonthNumber = 2; 
    } else if (month1.equalsIgnoreCase("March")){      
        firstMonthNumber = 3;
    } else if(month1.equalsIgnoreCase("April")){     
        firstMonthNumber = 4; 
    } else if (month1.equalsIgnoreCase("May")){      
        firstMonthNumber = 5;
    } else if(month1.equalsIgnoreCase("June")){     
        firstMonthNumber = 6; 
    } else if (month1.equalsIgnoreCase("July")){      
        firstMonthNumber = 7;
    } else if(month1.equalsIgnoreCase("August")){     
        firstMonthNumber = 8; 
    } else if (month1.equalsIgnoreCase("September")){      
        firstMonthNumber = 9;
    } else if(month1.equalsIgnoreCase("October")){     
        firstMonthNumber = 10; 
    } else if (month1.equalsIgnoreCase("November")){      
        firstMonthNumber = 11;
    } else if(month1.equalsIgnoreCase("December")){     
        firstMonthNumber = 12; 
    }
    if (month2.equalsIgnoreCase("January")){      
        secondMonthNumber = 1;
    } else if(month2.equalsIgnoreCase("February")){     
        secondMonthNumber = 2; 
    } else if (month2.equalsIgnoreCase("March")){      
        secondMonthNumber = 3;
    } else if(month2.equalsIgnoreCase("April")){     
        secondMonthNumber = 4; 
    } else if (month2.equalsIgnoreCase("May")){      
        secondMonthNumber = 5;
    } else if(month2.equalsIgnoreCase("June")){     
        secondMonthNumber = 6; 
    } else if (month2.equalsIgnoreCase("July")){      
        secondMonthNumber = 7;
    } else if(month2.equalsIgnoreCase("August")){     
        secondMonthNumber = 8; 
    } else if (month2.equalsIgnoreCase("September")){      
        secondMonthNumber = 9;
    } else if(month2.equalsIgnoreCase("October")){     
        secondMonthNumber = 10; 
    } else if (month2.equalsIgnoreCase("November")){      
        secondMonthNumber = 11;
    } else if(month2.equalsIgnoreCase("December")){     
        secondMonthNumber = 12; 
    }

    totalYear = year1 - year2;
    totalMonth = firstMonthNumber - secondMonthNumber;
```

Comment: DO NOT paste links. Paste the code here itself.

Answer (score 2):

Java 8 has nice classes for this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    test("June, 1999", "April, 2002");
}
private static void test(String fromMonthYear, String toMonthYear) {
    DateTimeFormatter monthYearFormat = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMMM, uuuu");
    YearMonth from = YearMonth.parse(fromMonthYear, monthYearFormat);
    YearMonth to   = YearMonth.parse(toMonthYear  , monthYearFormat);
    long months = from.until(to, ChronoUnit.MONTHS);
    System.out.printf("%d years and %d months%n", months / 12, months % 12);
}
```

*Output*

```
2 years and 10 months
```

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there. Just need to do this:

```
if(numOfMonth < 0) {
   numOfMonth = 12 + numOfMonth;
   numOfYears = numOfYears - 1; 
}
```

Comment: `numOfMonth += 12;` and `numOfYears--;` would be better.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
String dateStart = "01/14/2012 09:29:58";
String dateStop = "01/15/2012 10:31:48";
 SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");

Date d1 = null;
Date d2 = null;

try {
    d1 = format.parse(dateStart);
    d2 = format.parse(dateStop);

    DateTime dt1 = new DateTime(d1);
    DateTime dt2 = new DateTime(d2);

    System.out.print(Days.daysBetween(dt1, dt2).getDays() + " days, ");
    System.out.print(Hours.hoursBetween(dt1, dt2).getHours() % 24 + " hours, ");
    System.out.print(Minutes.minutesBetween(dt1, dt2).getMinutes() % 60 + " minutes, ");
    System.out.print(Seconds.secondsBetween(dt1, dt2).getSeconds() % 60 + " seconds.");

 } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
 }
```

Note : import `org.joda.time.*`jar in your java application this API have so many methods enjoy coding

Comment: Did you read the question? Input is `June, 1999` and `April, 2002`. Output should be `2 years and 10 months`. Pure **year** and **month**. This answer does everything *except* year and month.